# fill() function in spark not working properly

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[image]

This is the dataset, and I am trying to fill all the null values with '*****'.

`data.na.fill('*****').show()`
Ideally, this statement should fill all the nulls with asterisk. But only the city column's nulls are getting replaced. Don't know why.

Comment: Looking at your image, only `city` has a string type column, rest are numerics. and your fill value is a string hence only city column is getting replaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fillna](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna.html) depends on the schema of your underlying dataset.

As the document states - `fillna(value, subset=None)`

> value must be a mapping from column name (string) to replacement value. The replacement value must be an int, float, boolean, or string.

Below is an exmaple to demonstrate the same

## Data Preparation

```
input_str = """
|1  |704    |STANDARD|null               |PR   |30100
|2  |null    |null    |PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|PR   |null
|3  |709    |null    |BDA SAN LUIS       |PR   |3700
|4  |null  |UNIQUE  |CINGULAR WIRELESS  |TX   |84000
|5  |76177  |STANDARD|null               |TX   |null
""".split("|")

input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, input_str[1:]))

n = len(input_values)

cols = ['id','zipcode','type','city','state','population']

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+6]) for i in range(0,n,6)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, cols)

sparkDF.show()

+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
| id|zipcode|    type|               city|state|population|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
|  1|    704|STANDARD|               null|   PR|     30100|
|  2|   null|    null|PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|   PR|      null|
|  3|    709|    null|       BDA SAN LUIS|   PR|      3700|
|  4|   null|  UNIQUE|  CINGULAR WIRELESS|   TX|     84000|
|  5|  76177|STANDARD|               null|   TX|      null|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- zipcode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- population: string (nullable = true)
```

## FillNa

FillNa directly without casting , as the schema is `string` , would replaces all the null values to `***`

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.na.fill('****')

sparkDF.show()

+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
| id|zipcode|    type|               city|state|population|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
|  1|    704|STANDARD|               ****|   PR|     30100|
|  2|   ****|    ****|PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|   PR|      ****|
|  3|    709|    ****|       BDA SAN LUIS|   PR|      3700|
|  4|   ****|  UNIQUE|  CINGULAR WIRELESS|   TX|     84000|
|  5|  76177|STANDARD|               ****|   TX|      ****|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
```

## Casting & FillNa

Casting `population` and `id` to DoubleType , and filling with `0` populates the null values within the `DoubleType` columns to 0

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('zipcode',F.col('zipcode').cast(DoubleType()))\
                 .withColumn('population',F.col('population').cast(DoubleType()))

sparkDF = sparkDF.na.fill(0)

sparkDF.show()

+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
| id|zipcode|    type|               city|state|population|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
|  1|  704.0|STANDARD|               null|   PR|   30100.0|
|  2|    0.0|    null|PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|   PR|       0.0|
|  3|  709.0|    null|       BDA SAN LUIS|   PR|    3700.0|
|  4|    0.0|  UNIQUE|  CINGULAR WIRELESS|   TX|   84000.0|
|  5|76177.0|STANDARD|               null|   TX|       0.0|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
```